# Passing instance variable to webpacker JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

in a Rails app, is it possible to pass the current instance variable to the javascript file loaded through webpacker (not sprockets)?
This could prevent me to pass data to a component based framework like Vue by doing something like:

```rb
const el = <%= @employees.to_json %>
```

My idea is to simplify it so that I don't need to use Rails as an API while still providing data to a front end framework.
The idea of putting data inside a div or form in the HTML seems messy to me.
I even thought if I could create an empty javascript file loaded on sprocket where I just create the variables which I then load in the file loaded with webpack but it could still be over engineering... Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) could help. [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).
Just set variable in controller:

```
gon.employees = @employees.to_json
```

And it will be aviable on js `gon.employees`

Comment: Thank you!!! Thanks to you I was able to create (what I think is) a nice Skeleton of Vue on Rails webpack only! (no sprockets)
https://github.com/JacopoGobbi/RailsSkeleton

Answer (score 1):

Can you "respond with javascript"?

In your controller you'll have something like this:

```
def index
 @employees = Employees.all # Load data
 respond_with do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then you'll have `index.js.erb`:

```
const el = <%= @employees.to_json %>
```

But that using Rails as an API

You can also put that javascript variable into `<script>` tag in the HTML

Comment: What I mean is to have the instance variable available for the js loaded with webpacker in app/javascript/packs but I think those js hold a different context than the one rails respond with or the html. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JacopoGobbi It doens't matter how the JS is loaded. If it is running on the user side, you can set it from rails, either in HTML DOM or through ajax request.

Comment: Hi, I checked better and instance variable are not loaded on webpack loaded css. Feel free to try by yourself by cloning this repo https://github.com/JacopoGobbi/RailsSkeleton/blob/aecb4f54d7908b7fb2a8590c9b97998aa924a6ff/app/javascript/packs/test.js.erb If you clone master you'll see I solved on the latest commit by using gon as specified by @vasiliy-shakhunov

Comment: @JacopoGobbi Ah I see what the issue was. `app/javascript` gets compiled way before the controller action. So that variable would never be populated at that time. However simple ruby injection will work.